# Set no wallpaper, but single color background

Tags: screen, wallpaper

I was trying to find the setting to disable the wallpaper on my Android phone.
I've found some suggestion which suggest to make a fake black png or something like that, but it's going around the problem instead of solving it. Technically, it's still a wallpaper, and I don't want to have any...

How to set **not** to use wallpaper on Android? There must be some way, even on Windows it's possible...

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S4

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest way to do this was with the application [Color Wallpaper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ellipselab.android.colorwallpaper). All the possible colors selectable from a menu, and i haven't changed the color in months. You can set it and forget it. Even uninstall after setting, if that is your wish.

Disclaimer: I am not the developer of this application, just a satified user - for years.

Comment: The app is removed from Play Store

Comment: Too bad. Maybe a new version is coming out.

Answer (score 1):

Came across another cool app, it's called [Hexa Time](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.priyesh.hexatime&referrer=utm_source%3D42matters.com%26utm_medium%3DWidgetWeb). You can try it.